# expandoobject + dynamic schema + entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I did a few searches but could not find anything really. I am just curious whether it is possible to create 'dynamic expandoobjects entities' (managed by some UI/API) and reflect these changes in some dynamic schema controlled via entity framework (via code first?). Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.